# Forming synchronous SR flip-flop from asynchronous SR flip-flop

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)) gives the following circuits of flip-flops:

1. SR latch using NORs

[image]

[image]

2. SR latch using NANDs

[image]

[image]

3. Clocked SR latch using NORs:

[image]

[image]

4. Clocked SR latch using NANDs:

[image]

[image]

I understand how circuit 3 is obtained from circuit 1. It just involves ANDing the clock input with inputs in circuit 1, especially it preserves the order of input. That is, note that in circuit 1, we have R input at top and S below it. Same is the case in circuit 3.

However, in circuit 4, which seems to have been obtained by NANDing the clock input with inputs of circuit 2, the order of inputs seems to have been reversed. In circuit 2, we have S' at top and R' below it, whereas in circuit 4, we have R at top and S below it. Should it be S at the top and R below it, in circuit 4?

Answer (score -1):

Two is correct, 4 is wrong. 4 should have S at the top, R at the bottom.

If, in 4, input to top left nand gate and E are both high then input to top right nand gate goes low setting the Q output. Q has been set by input to top left nand gate going high so this input should be called S and the signal between the top two gates should be called !S.

Comment: I dont feel its incorrect SR FF if setting S=0 sets  output Q=1. I believe such FFs are called "active low" FFs. For e.g., have a look at [SR NAND FF truth table on wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)#SR_NAND_latch). I believe, for action table, only two orders are allowed: `Forbidden -> Reset -> Set -> No Change` or reverse: `No Change -> Set -> Reset -> Forbidden`. Circuit 4 results in order `No Change -> Set -> Reset -> Forbidden` which is not acceptable as a latch, thats why circuit 4 is incorrect, right? (added truth tables to question, please check)

Comment: For the nand gate latch shown in '2' the inputs are labelled correctly because the Q output is set by the '!S' input being taken to the active low state. The inputs are labelled according to their effect on the Q output. Therefore the inputs are active low. For circuit number '4' the active state of the inputs is now high (both low and their is no output change) and the Q output is set high by a high on the top input therefore this input should be called 'S'. Any sequence of the inputs and therefore the outputs is acceptable for either '2' or '4' with one exception - …….

Comment: .......The exception is, if the latch is in the forbidden state (which for circuit '2' is both inputs low and both outputs high) then both the inputs should not change to high simultaneously, if they do change to high simultaneously then the latch will end up in an indeterminate state with one output high and one output low (but it is impossible to predict which will be high and which low). Which is high and which is low will be determined by the relative speed of the two gates. If the latch is in the 'forbidden' state then for circuit '2' we must make sure we move from line 1 to line 2 or 3.